# finding a projection on tensor spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

I want to specify a projection from $V \otimes W$ to itself . How should I go about doing this ? And, can I charcterize all such projections that are possible ?

Edit 1 : $V$ and $W$ are any two vector spaces .

Edit 2 :I am looking for some projections that one may come across specifically 
        while studying tensor products of vector spaces . I am a novice learner and 
        I would get to understand projections and tensor products better if I come 
        across specific examples of such projections .

Comment: What are $V$ and $W$? Are they inner product spaces?

Comment: They are any two vector spaces .

Comment: What sort of property are you looking for in the projection? Usually you would want to specify the image or something like that.

Comment: My aim is to understand  how  to cook up a projection from $V \otimes W$ to $V \otimes W$ . There is no restriction on the image set . (Obviously , the id function will be a projection , but I want some non-trivial examples of projections .)

Comment: This is just an $nm$-dimensional vector space where $n$ and $m$ are the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ (or of a suitable infinite cardinality if these are not finite). Being a tensor product does not change the structure just as a vector space.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft please see edited question .

Comment: The edit does not change my comment. Being a tensor product is not inherently a property of the space, so it will not change what projections one might find.